# Can MessageChannel overflow

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on an AS3 project in FDT6. I am using the lastest FLEX 4.6 and AIR 3.7.

I have a worker.swf file that is embedded into the main application to do threading work with.

I am using the MessageChannel class to pass information between the two.

In my main class I have defined

```
private var mainToWorker:MessageChannel;
private var workerToMain:MessageChannel;

mainToWorker = Worker.current.createMessageChannel(worker);
workerToMain = worker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);
```

on the mainToWorker I only ever send messages. In these messages I send a byte array of information. The information is an object that contains a 'command' property and a 'props' property. Basically acting like a function call. The command is a function name and the props is an object that contains data for that function.

```
mainToWorkerMutex.lock();
mainToWorker.send(ByteArrayUtils.ObjectToByteArray({command:"DoSomething", props:{propA:1,propB:7}}));
mainToWorkerMutex.unlock();
```

The same occurs for the workerToMain var except I only send byte data that contains the 'message' and 'props' parameters.

```
workerToMainMutex.lock();
workerToMain.send(ByteArrayUtils.ObjectToByteArray({command:"complete", props:{return:"result"}}));
workerToMainMutex.unlock();
```

As a sanity check I make sure that the message channels are getting what they should.

It is working fine when I build it in FDT, however when it is built using an ANT script through flash builder I am sometimes getting the 'command' events coming back through in the workerToMain channel.

I am sending quite a lot of data through the message channel. Is it possible that I am overloading it and causing a buffer overflow into the other message channel somehow? How could that only be happening in FB?

I have checked my code many times and I am sure there is nothing in my own code that is sending that message back.

Comment: As a note, I just tried to run the working FDT build in a web browser outside of FDT and it looks like it's broken. So it seems that there is an issue with the messagechannel class that FDT has somehow gotten around with their swf viewer.

Comment: Perhaps since running the SWF from FDT in a browser caused an issue you should also see if running the swf built from the ant script when executed in the FDT swf player works or not.  This way you can determine if it's related to the context of execution (runtime) or compilation.

Comment: According to the docs you're not supposed to instantiate these directly: You do not create MessageChannel instances directly by calling the MessageChannel() constructor. To create a MessageChannel instance, call the createMessageChannel() method of the Worker object that will send messages on the channel, passing the receiving Worker object as an argument.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/MessageChannel.html

Comment: Last comment for now, I don't see any hard set limits, generally if there is no explicit limit you're just limited on device RAM.  Only mention of limits appears to be in the send method: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/MessageChannel.html#send()

Comment: I edited the code to show what I am actually using. I was just typing it in quickly. My mistake.

Comment: I just tried building it and running it with and ANT script through FDT and the exact same issue was occurring.

Comment: Perhaps check out dump-config and load-config compiler options http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html not sure where you need to put this for FDT though.  You should be able to somehow add the option to dump-config to both FDT and your ANT script then diff the output.  Possibly just load-config from the dump-config but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like I have found the issue. Looks like it's the ByteArray that is doing it.

ByteArray.toString() is basically sometimes mangles your data meaning you can't really trust it.

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=155067

If you read the comment by "Jim Freer" he mentions how strings sometimes do this.

My solution was to switch to using a JSON encoded string instead of ByteArray data in the message channel. The reason I was using bytearray data to begin with is because I wanted to preserve class definition information, which JSON doesn't do.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. When sending many bytearrays using channels sometimes things i received was not things i've actually sended. I had 4 channels (message channel to worker, message channel to main, data channel to worker, data channel to main).

I've noticed that data channel to main was affecting message channel to worker. When i turned off data channel to main - message channel to worker stared working just fine :D...

They have a big issue there with sending byte arrays it seems.

But what helped me was using **shareable** (at first it was not shareable) bytearray for communication via channels, but only for communication, as soon as i am receiving such bytearray i'm copying it to another byte array and parsing a copy.

This removed the problem (made quite hard stress tests there)...

Cheers

P.S. I'm also using static functions (like your ByteArrayUtils) to create bytearray's used for communication, but it seems fine, even made tests using non static functions.